# Day number of the year: date('z') + 1; (1..366) in (001..366) format

Tags: php, date

How to display the day of the year in 3 digits format so that January 1st is not "1", but "001"?

I'm curious as to whether such a function is implemented (something like date('zzz') ) or not, so I have to work on date('z') and check if it's less than 100, 10?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`strtotime` usage is discouraged. This should work:

```
echo sprintf('%03d', date('z'));
```

Comment: Never use `echo sprintf()` in any code for any reason.  It only makes sense to use `printf()` if you are going to print the value.

Answer (score 3):

```
function pad_date($date)
{
    return str_pad(date('z', $date), 3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
```

It is better to accept UNIX time in the function as above and use the `str_pad` function

Answer (score 1):

If there isn't such a function, my approach to such numerical padding needs is usually to do this:

```
$three_digit_day_num_string = substr('000' . date('z', $timestamp), -3);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function pad_date($date) {
    $mydate = date('z', $date);
    return str_repeat("0", 3-strlen($mydate) ).$mydate;
}

echo pad_date(time())."\n"; // today
echo pad_date(time() - (100 * 24 * 60 * 60))."\n"; // 100 days ago
echo pad_date(time() - (200 * 24 * 60 * 60))."\n"; // 200 days ago
echo pad_date(time() - (300 * 24 * 60 * 60))."\n"; // 300 days ago
echo pad_date(time() - (335 * 24 * 60 * 60))."\n"; // 335 days ago
```

Comment: I think that this is probably either answering a different question or maybe is just too long an answer.  I'm not sure.